# Integral over product of functions is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Suppose a measurable function $|g(x)|\leq M$ is bounded above by $M>0$.

If for every interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ $$\int_a^b g(x)\,dx=0$$
Is the following statement true?

$$\forall f\in L^1,\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(x)dx = 0$$

I am not sure how to proceed, and thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Your sentence *Is it true for all $f\in L^1$ such that the following holds?* is not clear and even more ambiguous vs. mathematical sentences.

Comment: Are you asking, if you know $\int_a^b g(x) dx = 0$, do you get $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = 0$ for all $f \in L^1$? The answer is absolutely not as you can see by playing with practically any example. Try $a=-1,b=1,g(x)=x$ for instance. The statement that you want is if $\int_c^d g(x) dx = 0$ for all $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$ and $g \in L^\infty$ then $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = 0$ for all $f \in L^1$.

Comment: My apologies, just realized that I did not state the question properly, and it was just edited, hope it looks better now.

Comment: Approximate $f$ by a sum of characteristic functions of intervals.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds pretty reasonable. But I was wondering if the density of $L^1$ space is enough for such an approximation or I need to show more work to come up with this approximation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this can work in general. Take for instance $f(x)=g(x)=\sin(x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$, then
$$\int_0^{2\pi} g(x)\,dx=0$$
however
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(x)\,dx>0$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry, I think I didn't state the question properly. So the issue is that $\int_a^b g(x)\, dx = 0$ for any $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$. So, I think $g(x)=\sin(x)$ doesn't satisfy. Do you have an idea after I edited my question?